# Div will not sit above Jquery slider

Tags: jquery, css, html, slider

I have a simple basic JQuery image slider which works great but I am trying to place a div over the top. Now it works if I place the div to each slide but I wish to have one div sitting there while the images fade in to the next.

```
<div id="slider-wrapper" style="margin-top: 100px;">

        <div style="float: left; background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);  padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px; width: 450px; height: 165px; z-index: 99999;">
        <h1 style="font-size: 28pt;">
        <?php include("profileuserdata.php"); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="editslide">
        <ul id="jsddm">
        <li><a href="#">Change</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Upload File</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">From Your Folio...</a></li>
        </ul>
        </ul>
        </div>




        <div id="slider">

        <div class="sp" style="background:url(http://topwalls.net/wallpapers/2012/11/Wallpaper-Rays-Color-Black-Background-1024x1024.jpg); width: 980px; height: 340px; padding-top: 120px; paddin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: -40px; margin-bottom: 0px;">

        </div>
```

The reason it cannot be applied to each slide is because the div I am overlaying contains user data which can be edited on the fly by the user but if the div is sitting on a slide when it moves to the next image the edit box will only show when it comes back around to that slide...

I have used z-index and can see the div underneath the sliding images when it fades out here is the css for the slider:

```
<style>
#slider-wrapper {width:500px; height:200px; z-index: 00000;}
#slider {width:500px; height:200px; position:relative;z-index: 00000;}
.sp {width:500px; height:200px; position:absolute;z-index: 00000;}
</style>
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a few div end-tags to start with

Comment: @Anders this only a snippet form the top of the slider code don't worry about the end divs...

Comment: I see! Which div do you want to show on top, and which div contains the image?

Comment: The div that needs to be sitting on top is the one that isnt named but starts with div style="float..." The div id called slider is where the image sits.

Comment: Well in actual face the div class called sp is the image but it will work if I plonk the above mentioned in there but I want it to sit on top of the image slider as a whole and not just the one image if that makes sense?

Comment: So you are probably looking for `position: fixed`. But to be honest - I do not understand which of your DIV elements is for the respective content!? And what code will be inserted by PHP? I guess your overlaying (edit) DIV should be positioned fixed against the "slider-wrapper" and using `z-index` to set it above the sliding images.

Comment: Does `#editslide`behave as you expect it to?

Comment: @Anders yes the div behaves perfectly ok. Everything does. However the div just will not sit on top despite throwing the slider divs to the back using z-index...

Comment: I fixed it by using position: relative; thanks for your help guys!